# How do I write the rule that has an edge server forward a clients request to an internal network server and back?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a network situation as follows:

```
-server1:1.1.1.1   
-server2:2.2.2.2    
-tunnel 10.8.0.0/24
-client: 3.3.3.3
```

I'm trying to have client `IP 3.3.3.3` do an `HTTP` request from the `1.1.1.1 server`. However I want the `1.1.1.1` server to pass this request onto the real `HTTPD` server `2.2.2.2`. The server `2.2.2.2` resides on the other end of my tunnel and has an `IP` of `10.8.0.6`. I want the traffic to route from `client > server1 > tunnel > server2` and then back `server2 < tunnel < server 1 < client`.

I have tested various rules for `iptables` but just can't seem to get it to work properly.

On `server1`, I originally had:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 3.3.3.3/32 -j ACCEPT
```

and then put the following `nat` rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -d 3.3.3.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.6 -j SNAT --to-source 3.3.3.3
```

The outcome was that `3.3.3.3` kept on hitting `1.1.1.1` and `1.1.1.1` would still reply and not pass on the request to `2.2.2.2` through the tunnel.

I tried removing the `iptables -A INPUT -s 3.3.3.3/32 -j ACCEPT` rule thinking maybe the rule was being read first in the tables list and thus letting `1.1.1.1` reply since that rule came before the `nat` rules but that was not the case. I removed the rule and all traffic from `3.3.3.3` to `1.1.1.1` stopped, which I was afraid would happen and it did.

How do I write a rule that allows `3.3.3.3` to talk to `2.2.2.2` but keep the traffic routing back through `1.1.1.1`?

Thanks